# how to run native mongodb commands in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular, angular2-meteor

How can I run the mongodb aggregate or $sum commands in angular2 ?

Comment: do you want to run these command in minimongo ? i think minimongo don't support these. you can manually do it in frontend. get all data from mongodb and apply forloop with your condition